# Why is $\{\omega:f(\omega)\leq g(\omega)\}$ measurable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ be a masure space and $f,g:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\rightarrow(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ be measurable functions. Is $E:=\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)\leq g(\omega)\}$ measurable, i.e. in $\mathcal F$?

I ask because this is used (in the special case of $f$ being a nonnegative simple function and $g$ being a nonnegative measurable function) in the proof of the theorem of monotone convergence, and I have two sources that just note that $E$ is measurable, but don't note why, so I guess it is really obvious and I simply miss something.

Comment: Its complement is $\cup_{r \in \mathbb q} \{f(x) >r\} \cap  \{g(x) <r\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent $E$ as a preimage of a measurable set under a measurable function. In particular,

$$E=(f-g)^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$$